# How to list all user specified files using glob in python

Tags: python, glob

This is what I am trying to accomplish:
In my dir, there are many files but they all follow a format

aaa001
aaa002
aaa003
bbb001
bbb002
bbb003
ccc001
ccc002
ccc003
etc.

What I'm trying to do is get the "family of files" that a user specifies, meaning, I will read input from the user as to which file family they want (e.g. if the user enters aaa, I want to list out aaa001, aaa002, aaa003)

The command I'm trying to use/run is

```
files = glob.glob("%userInput.*\.csv")
```

userInput is the variable I'm using to store the user's selection.

However, it doesn't seem to be getting anything, which means I'm not using the command syntax correctly.  Can someone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an older (2.x) string formatting trick that goes like this:

```
files = glob.glob("%s*.csv" % userInput)
```

In newer versions of python (especially 3.x) you want something like:

```
files = glob.glob("{}*.csv".format(userInput))
```

Comment: The second example should work on Python 2.7+ (probably 2.6+, actually, since its using an explicit positional argument specifier), and could be simplified to `"{}*.csv".format(userInput)`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications, @dano; the change in string formatting is one of the biggest hurdles I've had trying to convert myself over to Python 3, and I obviously still haven't actually managed to grasp them.

Comment: @TML there's absolutely no reason to avoid classic formatting. Choose which one to use based on which is better for the given task. I do prefer the new style when using named arguments though.

Comment: I had thought that the old style was deprecated, but I'm not sure at the moment where I got that notion from. Thanks for clarifying, @o11c!

Comment: @o11c I agree that there's nothing wrong with classic formatting, but [the docs do say](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to prefer the new way: *"This method of string formatting is the new standard in Python 3, and should be preferred to the % formatting described in [String Formatting Operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) in new code."*

Comment: Well, at least I didn't TOTALLY imagine that. :)

Comment: @TML You should prefer `str.format` over `%`-formatting because it's more powerful and flexible. For example you can re-use positional arguments `'{0} {0} {0}'.format(1) -> '1 1 1'` while this would require using named parameters with `%` (and you cannot mix positionals and keywords in `%`-style formatting). Also there are some customizations that aren't available with `%` style formatting. Finally, `%`-style formatting has a bunch of odd behaviours in some circumastances that are avoided using `str.format`.

Comment: That's what they tell mee, @Bakuriu; but in 12 years, I've never had a problem with `%` formatting, and the documentation on the new format is pretty dense, so I've not made a serious effort at learning `string.format`

Comment: @TML I've seen people asking questions about odd behaviours of `%`-formatting here on SO. For example, `'' % (1,)` and `'' % {1}` raise an error ("not all arguments converted during string formatting"), but if you use a list `'' % [1] -> ''` no error whatsoever. And this is just one corner case; there are more. These kinds of inconsistencies make `%`-formatting hard to work with in complex situations, especially when the format string isn't a constant. `str.format` fixes most (if not all) these problems.

Comment: *shrug* I don't often find myself doing crazy string formatting tricks, so neither the consistency at the edge-case nor the additional power of the new formats have been compelling enough to make it worth dedicating the time to learn. I really only have two use-cases for string formatting in practice: I either have exactly one parameter (`'%s' % foo`) or I am using named parameters (`'%(foo)s' % {'foo': foo}`)

Comment: @TML, thx for the answer.  I was thinking in terms of regex and added all those extra characters and messed myself up.  (smh)